# $getJSON works on jsfiddle but not remotely

Tags: jquery, json, undefined, getjson, flickr

I'm still new to understanding everything I'm attempting to do, so I'm in need of some help as to what is breaking my code. In short, I want to take the json results containing the photo info, and target certain parameters to be contained in vars that I will need to use.

This code works just find in jsfiddle. It displays the Flickr photo's owner's username.

```
$.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=' + apiKey + '&photo_id=' + photoId + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
    function(data) {
        var photoOwner = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.photo.owner.username));
        $('#photoInfo').html(photoOwner);
});
```

When I put this code back into the rest of my JS file, it gives the error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'owner' of undefined
```

Below is a simplified version of my JS file (minus the apiKey and photoId vars).

```
(function () {
  var s = document.createElement('script');
  s.setAttribute('src', 'http://jquery.com/src/jquery-latest.js');
  s.onload = function () {
jQuery.noConflict();
(function ($) {

    $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photos.getInfo&api_key=' + apiKey + '&photo_id=' + photoId + '&format=json&jsoncallback=?',
        function(data) {
            var photoOwner = $.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data.photo.owner.username));
        $('#photoInfo').html(photoOwner);
    });

}(jQuery));
};
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(s);
}());
```

So I know the code works... I just don't know why it stops working when I get it into my JS file. Any help, advice, explanation, or better method of doing this would be much appreciated.

Comment: `$.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(...` why on Earth would you do this? `getJSON` already passes an object literal to your callback function. You don't need to turn it into a string and then back into an object

Comment: The error message suggests that `data.photo` is not defined. You should check the data coming back from the flickr API

Comment: Including jQuery the regular way and using a document ready handler would probably be better, then just use the object without parsing it twice, and make sure the object actually has the properties you're trying to access.

Comment: @Phil Clearly I don't know what I'm doing and am still learning, hence  why I'm here asking. But I do know the data is there because I can run the same code in jsfiddle and it returns the proper data. But now that I know I'm double parsing, I'll looking into not doing that :P

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like this...

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var apiKey = <insert api key>,
        photoId = <insert photo id>;

    jQuery(function($) {
        // do all this in a document ready handler to ensure the
        // #photoInfo element is present

        $.getJSON('http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?', {
            method: 'flickr.photos.getInfo',
            api_key: apiKey,
            photo_id: photoId,
            format: 'json'
        }).done(function(data) {
            var photoOwner = data.photo ? data.photo.owner.username : data.message;
            $('#photoInfo').html(photoOwner);
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('Could not connect to flickr API');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm going to check it out. Could you explain the structure of the photoOwner var? I'm following everything else pretty much... just not sure I know what's going on in the var. Thanks.

Comment: I just tried your code, and the same as my original code, it works perfectly in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4VuQT/ but throws "Photo Not Found" when I run it on my remote JS file. More information that may help, I'm trying to create a bookmarklet and thought maybe there's an issue with cross-domain access? I've read about that a little bit... but I figured if I'm using Flickr's API then wouldn't json format accommodate for cross-domain already? or do I need to specify something to force it as jsonp?

Comment: Any idea on that Phil?